# Linear independence and linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My questions are based on a set of vectors which are homogenous.

Am I correct by saying the determinant not equal to zero implies a trivial solution which also implies linear independence?

If the determinant is equal zero, does it mean there exists a linear combination? If not, please explain.

Comment: What are "homogeneous vectors"?? Do you mean *homogeneous linear* **equations** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, my guess is that this is referring to a matrix equation $Ax = 0$ where the matrix is the "set of vectors". And yes. The statements: $\operatorname{Det}(A) \neq 0$, the vectors are linearly independent and there is only the trivial solution to the homogeneous equation are equivalent.

Comment: @Brad, that could easily be a long shot in guessing, since the above is true iff the system is a *square one*, otherwise, of course, the coefficients' matrix's determinant isn't even defined. It is not clear the OP understand enough of this stuff to have this clear...

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant a matrix equation Ax=0, where the matrix is the set of vectors. And with regards to the determinant, I was referring to square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

[a list of properties equivalent to invertibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Properties)